# Why is SQLite 3 executing select queries one by one in Python?

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a Python application which is connected to SQLite database. When I hit the request it takes around 450 milliseconds to fetch 4500 rows of data which is a great thing.

But when I had 2 Python application of same logic (running in different port) pointing to the same single SQLite Database and when I hit the request of both the Python application in the same time, it took around 900 milliseconds to fetch the response. From here I came to a conclusion that the select queries are not executing in parallel, it is executing one by one.

Note: No write operations is needed for me. I just need to execute select queries.

A single request took 450 milliseconds. But when 2 connections try to read the database, it takes double the time.

Comment: I wonder if the SQLite engine is locking the file-based database, thus forcing each connection to wait until the previous one is finished. Do you actually need this to be fast? Is 900ms a real problem in your use case?

Comment: @halfer 900ms for just printing what it fetched from the database. I removed the original operation which is need to be done for testing purpose.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite is mainly used for single user apps and as such isn't really optimized for parallel query execution like you are trying to do.
You can either switch to a db engine that has concurrent access built in like MYSQL, PostgresSQL etc to achieve what you need and reduce the latency on getting the results for your queries or use SQLAlchemy to manage your pool connections opening and closing.

Comment: But in every websites they have given that SQLite parallelly execute the select statements without any problem. I have a doubt that do I need to change any configuration in sqlite for parallel reading of data.